# Find the person with most blog likes in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of blog objects, how can I find the author with highest number of likes in total?

I have tried using a for loop and pushing each object with a different author into a separate array, then calculating the total number of likes in the array. I'm having difficulties comparing the objects with each other and keep getting several arrays for the same author.

```
const blogs = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    author: 'Jane',
    likes: 4,
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    author: 'Joe',
    likes: 1,
  },
  {
    title: 'Third',
    author: 'Jane',
    likes: 7,
  },
  {
    title: 'Fourth',
    author: 'Jack',
    likes: 1,
  },
  {
    title: 'Fifth',
    author: 'Joe',
    likes: 5,
  }
]
```

The number of authors is not limited and in this example, the result should be something like:

```
{
    author: 'Jane',
    likes: 11,
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use reduce, map each author on object and add it's like

```js
const blogs = [ { title: 'First', author: 'Jane', likes: 4, }, { title: 'Second', author: 'Joe', likes: 1, }, { title: 'Third', author: 'Jane', likes: 7, }, { title: 'Fourth', author: 'Jack', likes: 1, }, { title: 'Fourth', author: 'Joe', likes: 5, } ]

let authorLikes = blogs.reduce((op, {author, likes}) => {
  op[author] = op[author] || 0
  op[author] += likes
  return op
},{})

console.log(authorLikes)
```

You can extend it further to get most likes

```
// to find most likes
let mostLikes = Object.keys(authorLikes).sort((a,b)=> authorLikes[b] - authorLikes[a])[0]

console.log(mostLikes, authorLikes[mostLikes])
```

Comment: Nice solution, but if goal is to find an author with the most likes, sorting the whole array adds unnecessary complexity of O(n * log n), when simply finding max value, which is O(n), is enough.

Comment: @VadimAidlin not sure how OP is using it in his project, so kept it in such a way so he/she can understand what's happening, if only max is needed, i would simply keep a key called max like and update it accordingly, if there are cases where are multiple max values,i will keep adding the names also in array, and later can simply access the values from that

Answer (score 3):

If you were solely looking for the author with the most likes, you could do this in one pass with [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

The method below keeps track of the authors' total likes (`sums`), and the individual author with the most (`most`), to simultaneously sum and compare.

```js
const blogs = [ { title: 'First', author: 'Jane', likes: 4, }, { title: 'Second', author: 'Joe', likes: 1, }, { title: 'Third', author: 'Jane', likes: 7, }, { title: 'Fourth', author: 'Jack', likes: 1, }, { title: 'Fourth', author: 'Joe', likes: 5, } ];

const getMostLikes = (blogs) => blogs
  .reduce(({sums,most}, {likes, author}) => {
    sums[author] = likes = (sums[author] || 0) + likes;
    if (likes > most.likes) most = {author,likes};
    return {sums,most};
  }, {sums: {}, most: {likes:0} })
  .most;

console.log( getMostLikes(blogs) );
```

<sup>* Thanks to [CodeManiac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56995642/11575449)'s answer, I've shortened the instantiation/addition using `out.sums[author] || 0` instead.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
const mostLiked = blogs.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return currentValue;
  }
  return accumulator.likes > currentValue.likes ? accumulator : currentValue;
});
```

Similar solution, although I find this easier to reason about.

Comment: This does not sum the values.